# always error "cannot insert value NULL" sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2008, update, null

I want to update table "tmpiscunitmap.tr_kpi_id" year_period=2016 
with value from table "tmp_kpi.tr_kpi_id where year_period=2016" 
with condition tmpiscunitmap.tr_kpi_id = tmp_kpi.tr_kpi_id on year_period=2015?

this my query and i get error "cannot insert value NULL into tmpiscunitmap.tr_kpi_id":

```
UPDATE tmpiscunitmap set tmpiscunitmap.tr_kpi_id=(
SELECT TOP 1
        b.tr_kpi_id
        FROM
        tmptr_kpi
        AS a
    INNER JOIN tmptr_kpi AS b ON a.tr_kpi_code = b.tr_kpi_code
    where
    a.year_period = 2015 AND
    b.year_period =2016 AND
    a.tr_kpi_id=tmpiscunitmap.tr_kpi_id)
```

Table tmptr_kpi:
[image: tmptr_kpi]

Table tmpiscunitmap:
[image: tmpiscunitmap]

Comment: Does `tmpiscunitmap` have a `year_period` column?

Comment: yes, column year_period value=2016, but value column tmpiscunitmap.tr_kpi_id = value column tmptr_kpi.tr_kpi_id on tmptr_kpi.year_period=2015, i want update value tmpiscunitmap.tr_kpi_id with value tmptr_kpi.year_period=2016

Comment: Is `tmpiscunitmap (tr_kpi_id)` the primary key of the table?

Comment: If you added a few sample rows from the 2 tables and the `CREATE TABLE` scripts, it would be much easier for others to answer.

Comment: tmpiscunitmap (tr_kpi_id) isn't the primary key of the table

Comment: Thnx for updating. Is it possible if you run the samples (for both tables) with the same 1-2 codes only, say with `where tr_kpi_code in (519, 552)` and update again?

Comment: in fact there are thousands of rows in both tables, and value in column tmpiscunitmap.tr_kpi_id it is definitely there in the column tmptr_kpi.tr_kpi_id just on year_period=2015, and i need to update tmpiscunitmap.tr_kpi_id from tmptr_kpi.tr_kpi_id on year_period=2016

Comment: Lets take the first row (with staff_code=1143, ...). What do you want changed and to what value?

Comment: staff_code=1143 , tr_kpi_id=396 on year_period=2016 isn't '396' in tmptr_kpi, all value column tmpiscunitmap.year_period is 2016

Comment: Can you run this and tell us the output? `select year_period, count(*)  from tmptr_kpi where tr_kpi_code = (select tr_kpi_code  from tmptr_kpi where tr_kpi_id=396) group by year_period ;`

Comment: |year_period|COLUMN1| 2014=12 ,2015=12,2016=12

Answer (score 1):

- First observation is that your update statement has no `WHERE` clause. This means that it will update **all** rows of the table. Are you sure you want that?

  From the comments, it seems that all rows have `year_period = 2016` and you do want to update all of them. In my opinion, it wouldn't hurt to explicitly add this condition in the statement. The opposite, it would avoid any unwanted changes, in case you run it in the future, say next year when you have rows with 2016 and 2017.
- Second, the error is due to for some rows, either the subquery returns a `NULL` value or it return no rows at all.

  You can easily find the "missing" values (those that the subquery returns no rows) with this:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT tr_kpi_id
  FROM tmpiscunitmap AS t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM    tmptr_kpi AS a
              INNER JOIN tmptr_kpi AS b ON a.tr_kpi_code = b.tr_kpi_code
          WHERE
              a.year_period = 2015 AND
              b.year_period = 2016 AND
              a.tr_kpi_id = t.tr_kpi_id
        ) 
  --  AND year_period = 2016 
   ;
  ```